# What is the default port to connect to Airbnb Caravel UI?

Tags: port, data-visualization, apache-superset

I have the installation done on my Mac. What local port does Caravel run on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has got no default port, instead we need to provide the port number when we start the Superset service.

```
superset runserver -p Port_Number
```

And it should get going..

Answer (score 2):

Default port is 8088.

```
# Start the web server on port 8088, use -p to bind to another port
superset runserver
```

This is directly copied from [The Superset installation guide](http://airbnb.io/superset/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization).